# Spring session scoped bean in EJB 2 Stateless Session Bean

Tags: java, spring, ejb

I'm adding some features to an old EJB 2 application using Spring.  The Spring application context used by the EJBs is a parent context of the web application as described [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/).

I'm trying to use a session scoped bean from within the EJBs.  The bean in question is initialized from the EJB application context.

However, I get this error when trying to access the bean:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'session'
```

[From what I've read,](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5011) this is because the parentContextKey is not an instance of WebApplicationContext.  Does anyone have an ideas of how I could get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to register the scope manually:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="session">
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I guess it should work, because `SessionScope` itself depends only on the thread-bound request context exposed by the `RequestContextListener` and doesn't depend on the application context.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use session-scoped Spring beans from within a Spring `WebApplicationContext`. There's no getting around this - no `WebApplicationContext`, no session-scoping.

Perhaps if you explained what you're trying to achieve, we could help further.  Are you perhaps conflating stateful session EJBs with servlet sessions? They're not the same thing.